# How to call a function with parameters after $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this an easy one for jquery pros.

I made a global function. It's called by an change event. But it also should be called once after $(document).ready

Simple story for a function without parameters.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function_to_call_after_ready();

})
```

But I have to call it with parameters, like this:

```
({param1: "1"}, function_to_call_after_read)
```

Tried several combination, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the original called by an change event:

```
$("#Verbrauch_Typ").change({param1: "#Verbrauch_Einheit", param2: "#Verbrauch_Typ"}, einheiten_filtern);
```

Works!

```
einheiten_filtern({param1: "#Verbrauch_Einheit", param2: "#Verbrauch_Typ"});
```

Doesn't and "disables" the whole script. Also teh change call doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I'm sure you've tried `function_to_call_after_ready({param: "1"})`

Comment: `function_to_call_after_read({param1: "1"})`?

Comment: And also `function_to_call_after_ready("1")`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `einheiten_filtern()` is an event handler that gathers additional data from the event object it receives.

You can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind to the `ready` event while providing additional data:

```
$(document).on("ready", {
    param1: "#Verbrauch_Einheit",
    param2: "#Verbrauch_Typ"
}, einheiten_filtern);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about `$(document).ready()` or the function you give to it. Just use a normal method call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function_to_call_after_ready("1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive what you're asking to do, but if you want to call a function with a variable number of arguments use `.apply`:

```
function_to_call.apply(window, arrayOfArguments);
```

If you want to change `this` in the context of the function, use either `.call` or `.apply`:

```
function_to_call.apply(jQuery, arrayOfArguments);
```

`.call` works the same, but takes individual arguments rather than an array of all arguments.

If you want to *bind* a function in this way rather than call it immediately, use `.bind` if available, or jQuery's `$.proxy`:

```
$(document).ready(function_to_call.bind(jQuery, arg1, arg2));
```

Neither `.bind` nor `$.proxy` take an array of arguments to act as the arguments.  They both take a variable number of arguments.